# Concurrent user Test using Jmeter

Tags: performance, concurrency, jmeter, performance-testing

I need to do load testing of a website with 100 concurrent user using Jmeter
I have created test plan Like this -

```
-Test Plan
--ThreadGroup
---Get Login Page
---Post Login Page
-View Result in Table
```

I made the below configurations in thread group for 100 concurrent users

```
No of threads = 100
Ramp Up Period = 1
Loop count = 1
```

Is it right approach for concurrent user test?

Comment: Use some duration in your test plan and `Loop Count= Forever`. After ramp-up time those 100 Threads will  then become concurrent. Otherwise use`Ramp-up Time=0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, you may or may not achieve 100 concurrent users, it will be dependent on application response time and how fast JMeter will be sending requests.

I would suggest to:

- either set Loop Count so something above 1
- or setting the Loop Count to `-1` (so your threads will loop forever) and define the desired test duration via `Scheduler Configuration -> Duration` section of the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) like:

  [image: Thread Group Scheduler]

  or do the same using the [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) guide for more detailed information on how does JMeter works and why providing enough loops is important.

You can monitor the actual delivered load via i.e [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener (available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)) or using [JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

[image: Dashboard active threads over time]

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri Its a better solution .

Comment: I have one more question here. I am simulating 100 login concurrent load and my csv file having 500 username and password. It is taking 100 user login which i am doing up in 1 second So  will it take other credentials for rest of the request till end time ?

Comment: It depends on [CSV Data Set Config settings](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG), to wit `Recycle on EOF`, `Stop thread on EOF` and `Sharing mode`.